# .NET MVC3 routing - why so confusing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I don't know why I constantly struggle with this, but can someone explain why this doesn't work?

`/` redirects to the `index` action of the `home` controller.

`/gallery/` throws a 404 not found error.

`/gallery/index` redirects to the `index` action of the `gallery` controller.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx):

> When you define a route, you can assign a default value for a parameter. The default value is used if a value for that parameter is not included in the URL.   You set default values for a route by assigning a dictionary object to the Defaults property of the Route class.

I don't understand how this doesn't follow that rule:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
    }
```

To me it reads:

- If a `controller` is not defined, use `Home`.
- If an `action` is not defined, use `Index`.
- URL entered contains a controller = `gallery` and an action **is not included in the URL** so it should be going to the `Index`.

Am I missing something or this unnecessarily confusing and silly?

I've always found MVC3 routing problematic but accepted it.  Then I started playing with Rails and Node frameworks and they have ridiculously simple routing so now .NET MVC just annoys me when it doesn't work or makes me use convoluted patterns.

For reference in case someone asks, my Gallery controller, Action and View are all defined and working when I browse to `/gallery/index`.

```
public class GalleryController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you only have this 1 route defined, the default route? No other routes are declared before it, and you are not using areas?

Comment: You are correct on all counts. Have you perhaps added another route?

Comment: No, I intentionally posted the entire `RegisterRoutes` method to make it clear only the default route is there.

Comment: Which IIS is this running in?

Comment: The built-in VS2010 virtual server.

Answer (score 5):

You definitively oughta be doing something wrong or there is some code you haven't shown us. Perform the following steps:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the default wizard (*Internet Application*)
2. Replace the contents of `HomeController.cs` with this:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return Content("home/index");
       }
   }

   public class GalleryController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return Content("gallery/index");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd>

Here's what happens:

```
requested url    |   result
-----------------+---------------
/                |   home/index
/home            |   home/index
/home/           |   home/index
/home/index      |   home/index
/home/index/     |   home/index
/gallery         |   gallery/index
/gallery/        |   gallery/index
/gallery/index   |   gallery/index
/gallery/index/  |   gallery/index
```

Exactly as expected, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed that worked as you demonstrated, now I'm going to do a diff and see what is different from my other app (which was an Empty project type).

Comment: Well this was officially one of those stupid developer moments.  For the sake of having a specific answer to the specific question I asked I'm answering my own question.  Thanks for the clarification though Darin, wish I could give more than just an upvote in situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was I had a hidden directory (not included in my solution) with the same name as my faulty route: `/gallery`.

Luckily I'm too tired this morning to punch my monitor.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions, all +1'd for helpful guidance.

PS.  To help me investigate the problem I used [Phil Haack's routing debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx).

Comment: Heh, +1 for not attacking your poor defenceless monitor `:)`